# Join 3 Database Tables with count 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

Asset 
AssetId | AssetName

Router
RouterId | RouterName

Tracking
TrackingId | RouterId | AssetId

I would like to count the number of Assets detected by each router that exists (has an entry) in Tracking table. So if I have 3 records of 3 routers in tracking but a specific Asset was only detected by 2 of them, the results set will list all 3 routers with count 0 for that Asset. I would like the results set to include RouterName, AssetName, Count(AssetId).

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    r.RouterName, a.AssetName, Count(t.AssetId) AssetCount
FROM 
    Tracking t LEFT JOIN Router r ON r.RouterId = t.RouterId
    LEFT JOIN Asset a ON a.AssetId = t.AssetId
GROUP BY
    r.RouterName, a.AssetName
ORDER BY
    a.AssetName
```

I only get records that have both RouterId and AssetId combination in Tracking table with that query.

I need the result like that:

```
RouterName | AssetName | AssetCount
Router 1 | Asset 1 | 2
Router 2 | Asset 1 | 0
Router 3 | Asset 1 | 1
Router 1 | Asset 2 | 0
Router 2 | Asset 2 | 4
Router 3 | Asset 2 | 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please share sample output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all routers, then it should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`s.  If you want to count assets, then it should not be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT r.RouterName, Count(t.AssetId) as AssetCount
FROM Router r LEFT JOIN
     Tracking t 
     ON r.RouterId = t.RouterId LEFT JOIN
     Asset a
     ON a.AssetId = t.AssetId
GROUP BY r.RouterName
ORDER BY r.RouterName
```